# Use memory location as hash key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a couple of objects that are on the heap:

```
const x = {foo:'bar'};
const y = {foo:'bar'};
const z = {foo:'bar'};
```

is there a way to put these in hash like so:

```
const c = {x: 'yolo', y: 'rolo', z: 'cholo'};
```

the only way this might work is if x y and z were represented by their locations in memory. I think this is possible in some languages, is it possible with JS?

Comment: You could serialize x, y, and z as strings.

Comment: @Scovetta - Except that in the example that would result in three identical strings.

Comment: @nnnnnn Good point, though I guess they might be identical objects anyway since they're const (copy on write).

Comment: @Scovetta: That’s not what `const` is, and they’re guaranteed not to be identical objects (`x !== y`).

Comment: @Ryan You're right -- was thinking about const strings. https://repl.it/GSMf/1 in case anyone is curious.

Comment: @Scovetta: Still not sure what `const` has to do with that… any strings with the same contents compare as identical.

Comment: @all yeah I used identical objects for that reason, it's a pretty bad idea to serialize them and use that string as the key for several fairly obvious reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [an ES6 Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
const c = new Map([
    [x, 'yolo'],
    [y, 'rolo'],
    [z, 'cholo'],
]);

console.log(c.get(x));
```

Comment: cool, can you confirm this uses their location in memory as a unique string? Must be right?

Comment: @AlexanderMills: “Location in memory” is an implementation detail; Map acts to its specification. For the case of an object key `a`, yes, nothing but `a` will get the corresponding value in the map.